# What is android:scheme in custom url in Android?

Tags: android, custom-url

First of all I need to know what is the use of custom URL?

```
<data android:scheme="cedemo" android:host="com.cedemo.scan" />
```

What is the "android:scheme="cedemo" in the above code , is scheme is userdefined name ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no component name and action attribute attached to
an intent
Android looks at the data portion. If the intent specifies a data URI, the
type is retrieved from this URI via ContentProvider.getType() if it is not already supplied
in the intent. The target activity must indicate through an intent-filter that it can handle
data of this type. If the data URI is not a content URI or the data type is not specified,
then the URI **scheme** is taken into account. The target activity should indicate that it
could handle the URIs of this type of scheme. There are a lot of info [about scheme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#scheme) which could help you. And yes, android:scheme="cedemo" seems to be custom scheme.